# Where can I get better glyphs in The Witcher 3?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I'm having a hard time finding better glyph's. It is my second play through, and I have looked many places. I'm starting to wonder if they even go over 2%. What are the glyph locations, in The Witcher 3?

Comment: I have tried to improve your question. It is hard to know what you mean by "better glyphs", though, and it might be considered too opinion based to fit. Why dont you start by telling us what Glyphs you have, or what you actually want to achieve feom your glyphs?

Comment: I am knew to this site how did you edit my question and thanks for the help

Comment: under the witcher tag, its one of the group of options.

Answer (score 8):

There are three levels of Glyph - Lesser Glyph (2%), Glyph (5%), and Greater Glyph (10%).

They can be found in loot, but this is random. The chance of finding better Glyphs increases as you gain experience.

You can also buy them from shopkeepers, armors and blacksmiths. Again what they have is random.

Finally you can find Diagrams for the different types of Glyph. With these Armors and Blacksmiths can upgrade Glyphs, but only if they have enough experience.

Comment: Without the DLC i know only one Blacksmith who can sell you the TOP Glyph Diagrams.

Comment: In Hearts Of Stone, you can get better equipment via [Runewords (for weapons) and Glyphwords (for armour)](http://witcher.wikia.com/wiki/Runewords).